# Jsp html form validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, servlets, bootstrapvalidator

I have a very strange problem: After logging in my web application I got redirected by a servlet to my dashboard. In the dashboard there is a link wrapped in a nav bar using bootstrap

```
 <li><a href="DashboardUser.jsp">Add User</a></li>
```

`DashboardUser.jsp` is a form to create a new user. All form-inputs are marked with `required`. So if I try to submit the form without fill the textfields it works(no validation). The servlet gets all attributes with null and throws an exception with forwarding to DashboardUser with an error message

```
request.setAttribute("errorMessage","error etc.");
request.getRequestDispatcher("DashboardUser.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

After forwarding back the form validation starts working! Whats the problem before?

By the way: I need a form validation plugin,that works with bootstrap. I have tried some plug-ins, but none of them worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your `console for any errors`? While checking the `client-side validation` for errors, do not submit the page. Post the errors if you found anything.

Since you've asked, my suggestion would be try the [Form Validation](http://formvalidation.io/) which supports bootstrap as well.

To apply the validator to particular field:

```
$(form).formValidation({
  fields: {
    fieldName: {
        // Replace validatorName with the name of validator
        // validatorOptions will be passed as third parameter of the
        // validate(validator, $field, options) method
        validatorName: validatorOptions
    }
  }
});
```

You can find [**example**](http://formvalidation.io/developing) here.